# Select the rows with custom date format in MySQLi

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, datatables

I want to select the rows with custom date format in MySQLi. Here is the image of my database.

[image]

if the  **`publish_date`** is like *1540182298,1540182469,1540183281*

`$sql="SELECT * FROM new_enquery WHERE date_format(publish_date, '%Y')='2018'";`

Comment: which data type is the column  publish_date ??

Comment: Please be clear with your question and give as much information as you can.

Comment: I can see what this is but apparently OP has no clue.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not images.

Comment: I add time from a webpage with time() in PHP and column basically varchar type but now I want to select that column which is created in 2018 with the help of mysqli query. but how I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems unix timestamp  so you could try using FROM_UNIXTIME

```
SELECT * FROM new_enquery WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(publish_date, '%Y')= '2018'
```